# Inspect REST request and response generated by jersey and jaxb

Tags: debugging, rest, jaxb, jersey

I have a method:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String createQueue(JAXBElement<Queue> queueElement) {
    // do some stuff here
    return "";
}
```

Now, when I call this service from my client java application, I would like to inspect the HTTP request that has been created. I want to see the XML (request body) that is created by jaxb. Is there a tool that can observe requests / responses that are made on a particular URL?

Thanks in advance, Andreas

Comment: You don't need a Java client to access a RESTful service. Use any old HTTP client aka browser with the right tools.

Comment: He might know how to call it from a browser, but he also might want to see what his client code is actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple program that will act as a proxy and display the HTTP requests.  There are plenty out there.  Since you are using Java I suggest a simple [TcpMon](http://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/).  If you use soap a lot also, you can use the built in monitor in [soapui](http://www.soapui.org/).  If you also want to watch traffic from your browsers, you might consider [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Fiddler seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

For that I would use Firefox + [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network), which has nice network panel.

Answer (score 0):

Charles has a much better UI than Fiddler
Charles and Fiddler are proxy debuggers.
If you just want to sniff the http traffic I recommend Wireshark since it sniff the traffic at the Ethernet level and there is no proxy settings to change